# AngularJS eager loading json file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am new to angularJS. Sorry, If I am not clear with the question.

Here's the issue.

I have a JSON file ranging 20KB in size. When I try to load this file using 'factory' method, I am getting null value.

```
var app = angular.module('moonApp', []);

app.factory('MainSource', ['$http', function($http){
    var data={source:null};
    $http.get('/datafile.json',function(output){
      data.source=output;
      console.log(data.source); // it works
    });
    return data;
}]);

app.controller('appCtrl',['$scope','MainSource',function($scope,MainSource){
  console.log(MainSource.source); // Not works - getting Null value
}]);
```

For the above code I am getting NULL value in the console. But If i try it inside the $http success method, it renders the json file contents.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take some effort to actually learn about JavaScript before posting questions on JavaScript - this is an asynchronous call. Asynchronous behavior is a basic aspect of all JavaScript applications

Comment: This code uses the "data" variable both in the var line and as a parameter. Consider changing one of these to something else.

Comment: @DeborahK Thanks! I updated the variable to 'output'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using $resource to read json file. The following code can load a json file for you.

```
var app = angular.module('moonApp', ['ngResource']);

app.module('moonApp')
.service('MainSource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/datafile.json', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        }
    });
})
```

Now, inject and use the service in controller

```
app.controller('appCtrl',['$scope','MainSource',function($scope,MainSource){
   MainSource.query(function (data) {
    $scope.source = data;
    console.log($scope.source); // hopefully you'll see the JSON data here
   });       
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function on your `MainSource` factory and return a promise which you are able to resolve in your controller with the `then()` call. Please give this a try.

```
app.factory('MainSource', ['$http', function ($http) {

    function getSource() {
        return $http.get('/datafile.json', function () {
        });
    }

    return {
        'getSource': getSource
    }
}]);

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'MainSource', function ($scope, MainSource) {

    MainSource.getSource().then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
console.log(MainSource.data.source);
```